# Formatting device id and dates in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the following JSON response from the back-end:

```
{
  "assetStatus": "active",
  "auditLogs": {
    "20191115T123426": {
      "authorizedBy": "admin",
      "log": "Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:26"
    },
    "20191115T123427": {
      "authorizedBy": "admin",
      "log": "Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:27"
    },
    "20191115T123428": {
      "authorizedBy": "admin",
      "log": "Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:28"
    },
    "20191115T123430": {
      "authorizedBy": "admin",
      "log": "Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:30"
    },
    "20191115T142340": {
      "authorizedBy": "admin",
      "log": "Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"report\":\"\"}' at 2019-11-15T14:23:40"
    },
    "20191115T142402": {
      "authorizedBy": "admin",
      "log": "Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"report\":\"\"}' at 2019-11-15T14:24:02"
    }
  },
  "color": "red",
  "company": "Wizense Oy",
  "firmware": 0.19,
  "hardware": "B 2.0",
  "mac": "E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64",
  "mechanic": 3,
  "process": {
    "status": "OK"
  },
  "serialNumber": "HSKJRI891",
  "type": "wear"
}
```

My code:

```
  data = () => {
    let now = moment();
    console.log(`HERE DATE : ${now}`);
    const device_info_path = `/tenants/${tenantId}/assets/infrastructure/${this.props.macId}/deviceInfo`;
    const itemsRef = database.ref(device_info_path);
    itemsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.val().auditLogs == null) {
        console.log("00000 EMPTY LOGS");
        this.setState({
          no_data: "Empty"
        });
      } else {
        let keys_in_audit_logs = Object.keys(snapshot.val().auditLogs);
        let logs = [];
        keys_in_audit_logs.forEach(date => {
          logs.push({
            user: snapshot.val().auditLogs[date].authorizedBy,
            action: snapshot
              .val()
              .auditLogs[date].log.replace(/[{("':'")}]/g, ""),
            date: date.split("T").join("-")
          });
        });
        this.setState({
          user_actions: logs
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

This generates `logs` with entries like:

```
{
    "date": "20191115-142402"
    "log": "Config update for
            E529C7E2B764, fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e
            in iotCore with report at 2019-11-15T142402"
    "authorizedBy": "Admin"
}
```

How could I format the device id as `E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64` and the date as `2019:11:15-14:24:02` or any other readable format? I can `console.log` the formatted date with MomentJS, but it does not appear formatted to the user.

Comment: You are already using regular expressions. Continue to do so. Combined with destructuring you have your data

Comment: The data you process in your code seems to be structured, while the sample response you provided is plain text? Your code deals with properties such as `date`, `log`, `authorizedBy`. This just does not seem to match with a plain text response.

Comment: Also, you have a regular expression there that *removes* colons. And now you want them back in?

Comment: Response is plain text, i used regex to remove curly brackets and colon inside response, i have `date`, `log` and `AuthorizedBy` properties @trincot

Comment: You just repeated what I said. Not sure how that *answers* how come you have structured data (with those properties) in your response, when you say it is plain text. It cannot be both. Also why do you *ask* to get colon separators *added*, when your current code *removes* them??

Comment: I have the impression, the "plain text" you have given, is not the response, but the contents of `log` *after* you have done your processing. It would be most useful if you really would give the contents of `snapshot.val()` in structured JavaScript format.

Answer (score 1):

For device id you could have:

```
let deviceID = "E529C7E2B764"
// Here, a regular expression it's used, and it puts a ':' character 
// after each 2 chars. The result is: "E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64:". The last ":"
// should be removed, and this is the reason to use .slice method.
deviceID = deviceID.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:").slice(0, -1)
```

output: E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64

For the date - something similar.

An easy one is:

```
// The split method splits the string by '-' character. The return is an array of two strings in this case:  "20191115" and "142402".
let dateArray = "20191115-142402".split("-")
let date = dateArray[0]
let time = dateArray[1]


// Since the regular expression also puts the ":" character after each 2 chars,
// we have to remove the first one because of the year format.
// Before calling .replace(":", "") -> 20:19:11:15 
// and after -> 2019:11:15
// The slice method is used here also to remove the last ":".

date = date.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:").slice(0, -1).replace(":", "")
time = time.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:").slice(0, -1)

console.log(date + "-" + time)
```

output: 2019:11:15-14:24:02

Updated: Added comments.

Comment: It works well, can you explain how does it work or what is happening in the syntax please?

Comment: Added some comments

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your current call of `.replace` *removes* colons that were actually there in the MAC address:

```
 .replace(/[{("':'")}]/g, ""),
```

Now you are asking to get some of them back in, so I would first remove the `replace` call you already did, as without it, the MAC address will be as you want it. You just need to remove a colon from one other place, where a single zero follows it.

For the `date` property, you could insert the missing delimiters and then call `new Date` on it, so you get a real Date object.

See in this snippet:

```js
// Get an example snapshot object (this is just a mock, don't include this line)
let snapshot = mock();

let logs = Object.entries(snapshot.val().auditLogs).map(([date, {log, authorizedBy}]) => ({
    user: authorizedBy,
    action: log.replace(/[{("')}]|:0\b/g, "") // This does not damage the MAC address
               .replace(/(\d)T(\d)/g, "$1 $2"), // Remove the "T" from the date
    date: new Date(date.replace(/(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)T(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/, "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z"))
}));

console.log(logs);

// Mock for snapshot:
function mock() {
    return {
        val() {
            return {
                "assetStatus":"active",
                "auditLogs":{
                    "20191115T123426":{
                        "authorizedBy":"admin",
                        "log":"Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:26"
                    },
                    "20191115T123427":{
                        "authorizedBy":"admin",
                        "log":"Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:27"
                    },
                    "20191115T123428":{
                        "authorizedBy":"admin",
                        "log":"Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:28"
                    },
                    "20191115T123430":{
                        "authorizedBy":"admin",
                        "log":"Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"selftest\":0}' at 2019-11-15T12:34:30"
                    },
                    "20191115T142340":{
                        "authorizedBy":"admin",
                        "log":"Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"report\":\"\"}' at 2019-11-15T14:23:40"
                    },
                    "20191115T142402":{
                            "authorizedBy":"admin",
                            "log":"Config update for E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64 (fieldsight-octo-d82d3224-4c11-4b7b-ae18-36eac742710e) in iotCore with '{\"report\":\"\"}' at 2019-11-15T14:24:02"
                    }
                },
                "color":"red",
                "company":"Wizense Oy",
                "firmware":0.19,
                "hardware":"B 2.0",
                "mac":"E5:29:C7:E2:B7:64",
                "mechanic":3,
                "process":{"status":"OK"},
                "serialNumber":"HSKJRI891",
                "type":"wear"
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: But you do `Object.keys`, and get a `date`? So your JSON has more structure than you indicate here. Can you please log the contents of `snapshot.val()` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))` and tell us?

Comment: That JSON has one more opening brace than closing. Could you make sure it is correct? Also, what do you mean with "repeating"? A JSON should be self-contained. If you would just concatenate two JSONs together, it would not be valid JSON anymore. Please make sure to provide valid JSON.

Comment: I am sorry, I really want to post a good answer, but this JSON is still invalid. This part: `"auditLogs":"20191115T123426":{` is not correct. You cannot have two values for `auditLogs`, unless it is an array (which apparently it isn't). Could you please post valid JSON? I mean, if you just console.log like I suggested earlier on, there is no way you can get this kind of invalid JSON...

Comment: Works great thanks, i didn't realize that i removed the MAC address colons too, can you explain what is happening in the syntax please? @trincot